# Voltar na page anterior - mvc page razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, razor

Estou tentando voltar a página anterior, desta forma:

```
string urlAnterior = Request.Headers["Referer"].ToString();

        if (urlAnterior.Contains("Pagina"))
            return RedirectToAction("");
        else
            return RedirectToAction("");
```

Porém ele me retorna para a página atual atualizada, preciso voltar para a página anterior, como proceder?

Código que uso para chamar o create dentro de pessoas:

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <a asp-page="/ContaReceber/Create" asp-route-id="@Request.Query[" id "]" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Criar nova Conta</a>
</div>
```

E aqui é onde eu chamo dentro do Index de Contas a Receber:

```html
<a asp-page="Create" class="btn btn-primary">Criar nova Conta</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `RedirectToAction` espera como argumento uma string com o nome da controller ao qual você quer que redirecione, como esta em branco, ele redireciona para a controller do método atual. Então você deve colocar o nome da sua controller:

```
return RedirectToAction("SuaController");
```

ou se quiser chamar a Url anterior, faça assim:

```
return Redirect(urlAnterior);
```

Vi nos seus comentários que você quer redirecionar para uma pagina, baseado na origem da requisição que pode ser duas, você pode resolver mudando seu código original assim:

```
string urlAnterior = Request.Headers["Referer"].ToString();

if (urlAnterior.Contains("Pessoa"))
    return RedirectToAction("Edit", "Pessoa");
else
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "ContaReceber");
```

Mudando apenas os nomes dos controllers e métodos.

Comment: Ele me retorna o seguinte erro, qndo tento desta forma: InvalidOperationException: No route matches the supplied values. Depurando o código, eu pude verificar que na urlAnterior ele pega o valor: http://localhost:55695/ContaReceber/Create?id=2. Mesmo a requisição vindo da página Pessoa/Edit.

Comment: o erro ocorre por que não achou a rota:No route matches the supplied values, Mudei a linha do RedirectToAction.

Comment: você esta utilizando ActionLink? poderia colocar o código que você usa para chamar o create, contido na view.

Comment: Atualizei com a chama da página create. Tentei da forma que voce informou, dos dois jeitos ele retorna para http://localhost:55695/ContaReceber

Comment: Fiz uma demo aqui, e modifiquei as TagsHelpers dos links, usei  as TagsHelpers asp-controller e asp-action, dai a urlAnterior  vem com o link anterior correto. <a asp-controller="ContaPagar"
   asp-action="Create" asp-route-id="@Request.Query[" id "]">Criar nova Conta</a>

Comment: Fiz da mesma forma, ele sempre retorna para o Index de Contas a receber

Comment: ainda continua vindo a mesma url na variável urlAnterior?

Comment: Ainda continua, ela não redireciona para onde deveria, ela sempre retorna para o index de contas a receber.

Comment: mas apos as modificações, a urlAnterior continua vindo a mesma?

Comment: No page named './People/Edit?id=3' matches the supplied values. estou tentando passar direto, porém ele me retorna este erro.

Comment: você pode colocar este código no github? verifique no seu arquivo Startup.cs se as rotas estão configuradas.

Answer (score 1):

tente destas forma

ou assim

```
return Redirect(ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());
return Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());
return Redirect(HttpContext.Request.Headers["Referer"].ToString());
```

ou assim do lado da View

```
<a href='javascript:history.go(-1)'>Go Back</a>
<a href="##" onClick="history.go(-1); return false;"> Go Back</a> 
<input type='button' onclick='history.go(-1);' value='Go Back' />
<input type="button" value="GO BACK" onclick="location.href='@Request.UrlReferrer'" />

@Html.ActionLink("Back to previous page", null, null, null, new { href = Request.UrlReferrer})
```

Se Enviar o url por parâmetro também poderá usar desta forma

```
public ActionResult FilterData(string redirectUrl = null)
{
    // Do some work
    // ....
    if (redirectUrl != null) {
        return this.Redirect(redirectUrl);
    }

    return View("Default");
}
```

---

Tambem pode fazer assim

No controlar tambem pode usar assim

```
if(Request.Headers["Referer"] != null)
{
    ViewData["Reffer"] = Request.Headers["Referer"].ToString();
}
```

E na view (razor)

```
@if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ViewData["Reffer"]))
{
    <a href="@ViewData["Reffer"]">Return to client detail</a>
}
```

Comment: Não funciona pra mim, utilizo mvc page razor. Tentei editar conforme minha necessidade, porém ele não retorna para a página anterior.

Comment: Coloquei algumas soluções que podem funcionar mas precisaria de mais detalhes para ver o que está errado.

Comment: Tentei algumas que serviriam para o meu cenário, porém não deu certo, acontece o seguinte, eu tenho a page edit pessoas, e a pagina index contas a receber, dentro das duas eu chamo a create contas a receber, eu quero que quando ela vier de dentro do edit de pessoas, ele volte para esta página após incluir, e se ele for vim do index contas a receber, após incluir eu quero que ele volte para o index de contas a receber.

Comment: if (Request.UrlReferrer == "url index") {return view("nome da view") } Algo deste género ?

Comment: Eu tentei fazer algo como: if (idpessoa == 0)
            {
                return RedirectToPage("./Index");
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToPage("/Pessoa/Edit?id=" + idpessoa);
            } porém ele não consegue encontrar a Page Pessoa/Edit, e o parâmetro está sendo passado correto.